# Question about Server 2008 global catalogs and preferred logon servers

Tags: networking, active-directory, vpn, domain-controller

We have multiple sites with a global catalog AD DC at each location with VPN tunnels
VPN tunnels work as needed nothing wrong there ..

When clients at site B attempt to login and then run the set command it states that the logon server is the Domain Controller at Site A which over a small broadband link is bad any ideas how we can set it so that Site B "logs onto" DC B etc ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

I was looking at; http://support.microsoft.com/kb/192064 which may provide a workaround?

Comment: Are your sites setup correctly in sites and services?

Comment: Yep with full replication working fine

Comment: Do you have subnets set up in each AD site?

Answer (score 2):

You need to properly configure [Active Directory Sites and Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730868.aspx).

Things that you should be configuring in Sites & Services:

- Subnets
- Inter-site Links
- What Domain Controllers belong to what site
- Make sure that there is at least 1 GC at each site.

If you have this all configured, then chances are there are connectivity issues at the sites mentioned. If the appropriate DCs for a defined site are unreachable, the clients will attempt to authenticate over the lowest-cost link available.